# Compare and change list in Python

Tags: python, string, list, replace

I would like to change the identical elements across two lists using a given pattern. The element of the lists are strings like `'xxx.yyy...'`. So valid elements are e.g. `'aa', 'aa.1.2', '2.1.1'`.

Example:

```
list_1 = ['24' '1.1' '1.2' '2.13' '1.4']
list_2 = ['aa' 'bb' '1.1' '1.2' '1.3' '1.4' '1.5' '1.6' '24']
```

So in this case the elements:

```
'1.1', '1.2', '1.4', '24'
```

From one of the lists are common across the two lists and have to be changed like:

```
'1.7', '1.8', '1.9', '25'
```

So the root is kept and only the last portion is to be changed.
I can find if identical elements exists like:

```
for elem in list_1:
    if elem in list_2:
```

But how to change them accordingly?

Comment: "change them accordingly" to what? I don't see a pattern to the changes.

Comment: the next available integer at the end have to be used. So '1.1' have to be replaced with '1.7', '24' with '25' and so on.

Comment: Please post the expected output. Will your data set change or increase in size? Depending on the requirement the solution might be different.

Comment: @kotletschabowy one of the lists have to be changed. So one solution will be to change the list_1 like:
list_1 = ['25' '1.7' '1.8' '2.13' '1.9']

Comment: but then you better work with indexes and not elements: for indx in range(len(list_1)) and so on. His should not be difficult. But look at my answer, you can assign list_3 to list_1 and continue with your script.

Answer (score 0):

Using my crystal ball, I determined you want something like that:

```
def get_new_name(item):
    *head, tail = item.split(".")
    tail=int(tail)
    head = ".".join(head)
    while True:
        tail += 1
        yield head +"." + str(tail) if head else str(tail) 
for idx, item in list1:
    if item in list2:
        for new in get_new_name(item):
            if new not in list2 and new not in list1:
                list1[idx] = new
                break
```

The fancy argument unpacking will only work in recent versions of python (3), but are easy to replicate using other methods.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you want to create a new list and append there elements which are not in both lists unchanged and append elements which are in both lists changed.

```
list_3 = []
converter = {'1.1':'1.7', '1.2':'1.8', '1.4':'1.9', '24':'25'}
for elem in list_1:
    if elem in list_2:
        list_3.append(converter[elem])
    else:
        list_3.append(elem)
```

But this is wild guessing (and the code is "not pretty"), as your question is not fully clear.